# how to create new tables in mediawki 1.25+?

Tags: mediawiki

How is the hook set up to create new database tables when an extension is registered in MediaWiki 1.25+?

[The manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates) says

> Possibly the Hooks section of extensions.json should be used...

**What I tried**

in MyExtension/extension.json

```
    "Hooks": {
        "LoadExtensionSchemaUpdate": [
            "MyExtensionHooks::mySchemaUpdate"
        ]
  }
```

in MyExtension/MyExtension.hooks.php

```
class MyExtensionHooks {
    public static function mySchemaUpdate( DatabaseUpdater $updater ) {
        $updater->addExtensionTable( 'newTable',
            __DIR__ . '/table.sql' );
        return true;
    }
}
```

in MyExtension/table.sql

```
CREATE TABLE newTable ( 
   newTableID int not null auto_increment, 
   primary key (newTableID)  
);
```

I ran ../maintenance/update.php but no newTable was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook is called [`LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates).

Comment: I am glad you jumped in on this. However, link only answers are often a problem long term since links often break. Can you paraphrase the answer here for the user and future users?? Thanks! Cheers!!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/37351)

Comment: You seem to have jumped to the wrong conclusion from the fact that the answer is short and has a link in it. It is completely self-contained though.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your domain URL /mw-config/ and the update page will appear