# How to use the database table-prefix to create tables on LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates in Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

This relates to [a previous question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87630/how-to-create-new-tables-in-mediawki-1-25).

What is the proper way to include [$wgDBprefix](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBprefix) in the sql or hook function so that when tables are created or updated on [LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates), the created table names start with the value of $wgDBprefix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SQL code, `/*_*/` will be replaced with the prefix. For the table name parameter passed to the hook function, replacement will be handled automatically (but that is only used to determine whether the patchfile needs to be executed).

I've updated the [patchfile documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SQL_patch_file) a bit, you can find further details there.